Can "anachronism" mean something that didn't exist at the time under discussion?
My understanding of the word anachronism is that it means something is old-fashioned today, which coincides with #2 in Merriam-Webster.

a person or a thing that is chronologically out of place
especially, one from a former age that is incongruous in the present

I am wondering if anachronism can mean "opposite" of the above, that is, something that appears in a historical drama but didn't exist at that time (like, though not a good example, a cell phone being used in a movie set in the 1980s).
Cambridge definition seems to say yes, or looks like even says that it is more frequent:

a person, thing, or idea that exists out of its time in history, especially one that happened or existed later than the period being shown, discussed, etc.:

For some people, marriage is an anachronism from the days when women needed to be protected.


Questions:

From above, I suppose anachronism can mean things that appear in a story but didn't exist in the period where the story is set. Is this correct?

The Cambridge definition above looks confusing to me. Is it saying that anachronism more often refers to something like cell phone in 1980s? The example in the definition (and others in the link) looks more examples of old-fashioned sense of the word.



It's more common to encounter old things in the present than future things in the past, hence the Merriam-Webster definition. I've seen horse-and-carts on the road, I've never seen a spacecraft from 2100, even though both might be seen as anachronisms.

You often hear anachronistic dialogue in period TV dramas

In a TV documentary about Vikings recently, when the presenter was talking about sagas, the manuscript shown was from 14th century England, off by about 500 years.  And there's the Starbucks coffee cup in Game of Thrones.  Definitely out of place time-wise but not really "anachronisms".

Yes; the best generic working definition you could have that fits all uses of "anachronism" is "out of place in time." Obviously, in real life, we can't find anything that came from the future, like a spaceship from the year 3000. (Where we do find real things that seem futuristic or advanced, we use other expressions like "ahead of its time.") But when we set a work of fiction in a specific historical time, we might include elements from later times, and yes, this is absolutely a common use of "anachronism." It could be an accidental mistake, like showing a 1969 model of car in a movie set in 1965, or an intentional creative choice, like the movie Knight's Tale adding Queen's song "We Will Rock You" to a medieval jousting tournament. I can't say which use is more common (and it would be hard to find out), but the "out of place in the past" meaning is certainly common enough; here's a whole book about it.
It seems to be a rather confusing mistake that the Cambridge definition—"something that came from a later time"—is followed by an example sentence that uses the opposite meaning ("something left over from an earlier time").

I would say that an anachronism needs to be not only out of place in time, but deployed deliberately.  We wouldn't call the sound of an airplane overhead an anachronism in a movie set in the 1830s, if the sound was not noticed during editing and post-production and was thus simply an accident of circumstance. Broadly speaking, an anachronism is the result of a choice someone has made, a choice resulting in some kind of time-clash.
The pacifistic Amish in Lancaster County, Pennsylvania, with their horse-and-buggy, shown here in this clip from Peter Weir's film Witness, are an anachronism.  The Amish eschew motor vehicles and all things that use electricity.
The anachronism can also be the other way around, timewise: in a movie set in the Bronze Age, warriors brandishing  tempered steel blades would be an anachronism.

In 1960 approx I loved seeing a London 'Green Line' bus pass in the background of a Robin Hood TV episode. Film was expensive and deadlines strict, I later found out.

When referring to objects or expressions that are misplaced in advance of the time period in which they occur (versus being dated) here are two words that are a bit closer than anachronism: Prolepsis, Parachronism
